# NSTimer and server response

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I'm developing a messaging app and I have to make a call to a server every x seconds to load from server the new messages. 
I use a NSTimer that calls the server every x sec.
But for instance x = 1 sec and the response from server arrives after 1,5 sec. In this case I have one new request to the server that comes before that the previous request is satisfied, and this is a big problem for my app's logic. Can you help me to understand how can I check cyclically the messages on the server without have this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: How about using Apple Push Notifications to notify your app if a message has been received for the user? This way you will not have to constantly check in with your server to see if a message is waiting.

Comment: @sangony is right.Push notifications are better option.Also keep in mind, that this scenario will not work if your application is in suspended state. If you don't like Push notifications you can try Background Fetch API in iOS7.

Answer (score 1):

Stop your timer before starting your web request, and then start it again when you get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can send request to the server and once you have response (success/failure) send another one. In this scenario you will be sure that just one request is send and you can handle it easily.

Comment: I think that this is the best solution. The only problem is this: what happens if the server don't sends a response? There is not a way to retry a connection with the server.

Comment: If server don't see response you should see failure message (timeout) and as I said before send another response in success and failure case.